# Adjusting CSV Timestamp Format in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timestamp

I imported the contents of a SQL Server table into an S3 CSV file.

A `year_month` column was formatted as `datetime` in SQL Server, and appeared as `2020-01-01 00:00:00.000`. That same record appears as `1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM` in the S3 CSV file.

Is there a way to format the timestamp in S3?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is simply a storage service. Files in S3 will contain exactly what was uploaded.

If you wish to change the contents of the file, you will need to change the way that the file is generated before it is uploaded to S3.

Comment: Thanks. I resubmitted the question with additional information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61992855/adjusting-csv-datetime-timestamp-formats-in-aws-or-sql-server