# Adjusting CSV Datetime/Timestamp Formats in AWS or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, amazon-s3, timestamp

I imported the contents of a SQL Server table into an S3 CSV file.

A year_month column was formatted as datetime in SQL Server, and appeared as `2020-01-01 00:00:00.000`. That same record appears as `1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM` in the S3 csv file.

I am using this dataset in AWS Forecast, which requires `2020-01-01 00:00:00.000` formatting.

What is the best tool within AWS to adjust the format?

Or conversely, can I tackle the problem in SQL Server?

Comment: The Date and Time datatypes don't have a format. If you're exporting to something like a text file, then you need to tell the extraction process what format it should be in, or use `CONVERT` and a style code, to convert to a stylised `varchar`.

Comment: how did you do the import to CSV file?

Comment: @Greg - Via an Integration Services Project in Visual Studio using the Kingsway Soft S3 Connection Manager.